# display inline not making the div to move upward

Tags: html, css, css-float

[image]how to make the second div properly align with the first div....
i gave display inline for horizontal alignment...
but the second div is still down...
i am talking with respect to 24 inch monitor....

http://jsfiddle.net/ke6Se/1/embedded/result/

```
<div style=" width: 300px; display: inline-block;">
                  <span style="color: #000; font-size: 12px; font-family: arial; font-wieght: bold; margin-left: 45px;">Mark Up</span><span style="margin-left: 110px;">10%</span>
                  <div>
                    <span style="margin-left: 45px;">Non-Tax Amount</span><span style="margin-left: 59px;">0</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: What second `div`? Do you mean the nested `div`? If so, this code will not work as you expect.

Comment: Monitor size doesn't matter, resolution matters, the number of pixels. I'd recommending planning for a 1024 resolution unless you know ALL your user are going to be on a 1080p HD screen.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, as Kevin said in his comment, you're html is wrong.  You have one div nested inside the other.  Fix that and then apply inline-block to the second div

```
<div style=" width: 300px; display: inline-block;">
   <span style="color: #000; font-size: 12px; font-family: arial; font-wieght: bold; margin-left: 45px;">Mark Up</span><span style="margin-left: 110px;">10%</span>
</div> 
<div style="display:inline-block">
    <span style="margin-left: 45px;">Non-Tax Amount</span><span style="margin-left: 59px;">0</span>
</div>
```

[Here's the obligatory fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcurran/7edkK/)

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle is really busy and I can't find exactly where it is, but it has to do with your margins and widths.  You should set a wrapper `<div>` to a fixed width then `float: right` the `<div>` you want and make sure the `<div>`s widths add up to the wrappers width, including margin and any padding.  See this article for a good explination.

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/09/when-pages-are-not-paper-the-designers-guide-to-layout-code/

Also it might help to set a min width to prevent stacking of divs when the window is shrinked if you don't want to set a static width.

Here is a quick HTML mark up of what I'm talking about.

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 800px;">
    <div id="leftDiv" style="width: 600px; float: left;">
        I'm the left Div!
    </div>
    <div id="rightDiv" style="width: 200px; float: right;">
        I'm the right Div!
    </div>
</div>
```